# Fantasy series about magic and intelligent dinosaurs

Tags: story-identification, books, magic, dinosaurs

Recently, I remembered this book series I read as a kid, maybe 13 or 14 years ago. It wasn’t a children's books, maybe more like young-adult. I found a similar post on this forum from about 4 years ago, with no answer. It wouldn’t let me comment to ask if anyone had found anything, so I decided I might as well make a post.

Here is the link to the post I mentioned: [YA series of books about sentient dinosaurs in the Middle Ages](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/216034/ya-series-of-books-about-sentient-dinosaurs-in-the-middle-ages).
It mentioned a lot of details I had forgotten, so I copied the vast majority of it:

> It was about sentient dinosaurs that had evolved and changed, and lived in a medieval kingdom time.
>
> It was based around three protagonists, with the leader being a raptor-based dinosaur whose people believed in thinking as fast as their speed. There was political turmoil, and they had to run past a lava river into a hidden forgotten valley sealed by magic, because that magic was feared. The valley held a lost kingdom that had a magic flute they had to play to gain entrance, with side effects. There are mechanical beasts made purely of magic and three sets of armour: blue, red, and green, I believe. It is also magic or enchanted. There was a moment in the first book where playing the flute paralysed the main character, and he had to focus himself inward and command his claws to release it to break free.
>
> The second book is based around finding the lost fliers to join their war effort.

There was also this sealed tower in the castle they lived in which I believe had mirrors that allowed them to look all around the country, and was filled with cabinets that held various magic potions and the like.

I distinctly remember, at the time of my reading the series at least, that it was not finished, and probably never would be. I had my mom email the author to ask if there would ever be another book in the series, and I believe he replied with something along the lines of “probably not, it’s up to the publisher, not me.”

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you remember any details of the cover art?

Comment: Just to be clear, were there any humans in this world?

Comment: @DavidW I don’t remember any humans, if there were any they were very minor characters. I also don’t remember the cover art, but I’m fairly certain I’d recognize it if I saw it. Doesn’t help much here though lol